# TabBar is still clickable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tabbar

I got an App with a TabBar and I want to push a View on the complete display. Ok, that works.
The problem is, that the TabBar area is still clickable.

Is it possible to hide the TabBar complete?

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your subview on UIWindow.
For finding the main window, you can use

`UIWindow *window = (UIWindow *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];`

then you  can your subview to this window.

I hope this help.

Comment: I have used this. The other idea doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` when you want to hide the tabBar.

```
/* in the view that you are pushing to */
```

Comment: The tabBar is hidden. The problem is that it is still clickable.